# How I can make a dynamic splash through WS in swift - iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

I need to download and show an image on the Splash of my application. But I don't know if this is possible or a good practice on the splash, even I wanna know if there's a workaround to make this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*LaunchScreen.storyboard* (or Xib) is tremendously limited in functionality compared to a regular storyboard. You won't be able to do much on it.

The only possible way is to have a *SplashViewController* or the name you prefer as first Window's *rootViewController*. (can be defined in `AppDelegate`'s `application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` or *Main interface* in *General* tab of the Application target.

The initial layout of that first `SplashViewController` should be exactly as your `LaunchScreen`, trying to avoid a visual jump between them. After that you're free to show whatever you want.

Obviously, if you are going to do network load or any other type of task that delays the launch, it is convenient to show the user something that indicates this work. As far as possible cache so that in future launch the start is as fast and smooth as possible.